# Windows Subsystem for Linux(wsl)のDebianでPython3.7をインストールする

Tags: python, debian, wsl

wsl上のdebian(stretch)でPython3.7をインストールするにはどうすればいいのでしょうか?
stretch-backportsを検索してもPython3.5が出てきてしまいます。
さらに調べてみるとtestingには3.7があるようです。

WSL上のdebianでtestingからpackageを取得するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. testing を使う方法

WSL の Debian でも、通常の Debian と同様の方法で testing からインストールすることができます。ただし実装の差などの問題から、インストール後に何かしら警告やエラーが出る可能性はあります。

testing からインストールする方法は、Debian Wiki のページ [DebianTesting](http://DebianTesting) に解説があります。インストール手法だけでなく testing とは何かから解説がありますので、ご一読ください。また、紹介だけですが日本語での短い解説も[こちら](https://www.debian.or.jp/using/release.html)にあります。

インストール手法だけ抜粋・日本語訳すると、以下のような流れになります ("How to upgrade to Debian (next-stable) Testing" に書かれていることです)。システムを stable から testing にアップグレードする形です。**testing から stable には[やや戻しにくい](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117122/211480)のでご注意ください。**

1. デフォルトでは stable からインストールするようになっているので、まずは stable できちんと `apt update` できるか試す。この際 oldstable ではなく stable にしてください。
2. ファイル `/etc/apt/sources.list` を編集し、`stable` を `testing` にする。(この際、元の `sources.list` のバックアップを取っておくとやや安心です。)
3. stable のセキュリティアップデートを示す行をコメントアウトする (*security.debian.org* という文字列が含まれる行すべてです)。
4. `*-backports` や `*-updates` のような、stable のためだけの行をコメントアウトする。
5. `apt update` や `apt upgrade` 等をしてアップグレードする。

ただしこのやり方は Python に限らずシステム全体を testing 環境に置くことになります。注意してください。

### 2. Python のバージョンマネジャーを使う方法

testing を使うとシステム上の他のパッケージのバージョンにも影響するかもしれません。このため Python 3.7 が欲しいだけなら、Python のために作られたバージョンマネジャーや仮想環境を使うことをオススメします。

たとえば [tanalab2 さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/46734/19110)で解説されている [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) や、[本家 Stack Overflow の別質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46939562/5989200)で解説されている [Anaconda](https://www.python.jp/install/anaconda/unix/install.html) が有名です。[Yasuhiro さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/46768/19110)には他の選択肢も書かれています。

### 3. ソースからビルドする方法

また、Python 公式サイトから [Python 3.7 のソースコードをダウンロード](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/)し、自前でビルドしてインストールする方法を使うことでも、Python 3.7.x をインストールすることができます。

Answer (score 2):

`testing`を使うのは安定性の問題から通常は勧められません。安定版にインストールするのが基本です。

Pythonをインストールする話になると、日本ではまず`pyenv`が出てくるのですが、`pyenv`は、データサイエンスをしたい場合やWebアプリ等のアプリケーションを作りたい場合には向いていません。アプリケーションの開発中はPythonのバージョン等環境を固定するのが一般的なので、環境分離ツールには公式の`venv(virtualenv)`又は最近開発された`pipenv`を利用した方がベターです。パッケージの作成者以外では`pyenv`を使ったらいいというケースはあまりないと思います。

まず、初心者やデータサイエンスをしたい場合は、Anacondaが最適です。データサイエンスの場合、`Anaconda`を使うと楽ができます。パッケージがすべてコンパル済みになっているのでパッケージのインストールに面倒なことがない上にインストールが速いです。また、numpy, scypyは、インテルのMKLがリンクされたものなので、PyPIのバイナリーパッケージを使うよりかなり高速です。自分の経験では、最近購入したPCでは浮動小数点数のベクトル演算が4倍も違います。Anacondaには、`conda`という環境管理ツールが付属していて、複数のバージョンのPythonを切り替えて使うことができます。なお、Anacondaを使う場合は、PATHを通すと問題が出てくるので、`source anaconda3/bin/activate`でAnaconaの環境をアクティベイトするようにすると問題なく使えます。

Webアプリ等のアプリケーションを作りたい場合は、公式サイトからソースコードをダウンロードしてきて自分でビルドするのが早いです。unix.stackexchange.com の[「How to install Python 3.6?」](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332641/how-to-install-python-3-6)という質問の回答でもソースからインストールする方法が一番多くプラス投票がついています。自分でビルドするといっても以下のコマンドで簡単にインストールできます。

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
tar -xf Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
cd Python-3.7.0
./configure --enable-optimizations
make -s -j2
sudo make altinstall
python3.7
```

それらのコマンドを実行する前に、依存関係をインストールしておく必要がありますが、[「How to install Python 3.6?」](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332641/how-to-install-python-3-6)の回答では次ののようになっています。これは、`pyenv`でインストールする場合も同じで、`pyenv`は結局上のコマンドを自動で実行しているだけの話です。

```
sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev   
sudo apt-get install -y libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm 
sudo apt-get install -y libncurses5-dev  libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev
```

自分の場合は、それに追加して以下のdevパッケージをインストールしています。

```
sudo apt-get install iblzma-dev uuid-dev libffi-dev
```

Comment: `venv`に変るnpmみたいな`Pipenv`は公式ツールなんですね。勉強になります。ただ、`pyenv`と、`venv`or`Pipenv`の比較は少し違う気がします。`pyenv`はpythonのバージョンを手軽にインストール、切替するためのツールなので、`venv`や`Pipenv`と共に使います。

Comment: Webアプリをつくる場合、Pythonのバージョンを切り替えると動作しなくなる可能性があるので、手軽に切り替えるようなことは決してしません。また、データサイエンスの場合は最新のものだけで十分です。だから、pyenvは邪魔で、公式のものだけで十分です。

Comment: そうなんですね。承知しました。

Answer (score 1):

debianはパッケージのバージョンが古いことが多いです。

今後、各種バージョンのpythonをインストールする予定があるのであれば, [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)をインストールして利用すると、各種バージョンのインストールと切替が容易なため便利だと思います。

インストール方法は、以下の記事が参考になると思います。

[Windows10(WSL)で、2018年的Pythonプロジェクト（①pyenv/pipenvの導入）](https://qiita.com/Nimimal/items/72c2e2a6a566d1f5d2a2)

---

### pyenvの簡単な使い方

pyenvの使い方は、以下の記事が参考になると思います。

[Pyenvの使い方](https://qiita.com/mogom625/items/b1b673f530a05ec6b423)

以降にも簡単にまとめました。

pyenvをインストールしてしまえば、以下によりインストール可能なバージョンが表示されますので、そのなかから必要なバージョンを決めて、

```
pyenv install -l
Available versions:
  2.1.3
  2.2.3
  2.3.7
  2.4
  ..略..
```

以下により該当バージョン(例: 3.7.0)をソースからインストールできます。

```
pyenv install 3.7.0
```

インストールしたpythonを利用するには、以下を実行すれば、ログインしたシェル全体で該当バージョンのpythonを利用できます。

```
pyenv global 3.7.0
python --version
Python 3.7.0
```

プロジェクト単位にバージョンが異なる時など、特定のディレクトリ内でのみ該当バージョンのptyhonを利用したい場合は、以下を実行します。
(実行したディレクトリ内に`.python-version`ファイルが作成されバージョンが記録されます。)

```
pyenv install 3.6.4
pyenv local 3.6.4
python --version
Python 3.6.4
```

インストールされたpythonのバージョンは以下で確認できます。

```
pyenv versions
  system
  3.6.4
* 3.7.0
```

Comment: 日本は、多重下請構造で働いている人が多く、そこではPythonのバージョン等環境を指定して発注がくるので、pyenvを使う必要がある人がかなりの人数います。でも、それはかなり特殊な姿なので、できるだけ公式のものを勧めた方がいいと思います。

Comment: @YasuhiroNiji さん ありがとうございます。`pyenv`は日本特有の多重下請構造労働者向けなんですね。承知しました。